# Moveit Setup Assistant crashes when loading a URDF

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, ros-hydro, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am doing the Tutorials from http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/hydro/Exercises
During the Session 3 Tutorials Moveit! keeps crashing when ever I have to use it.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 (32-bit), ROS-I Hydro

I noticed that the Moveit Setup Assistant launchens when I start it with:

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

But as soon as I try to create a new moveit config pkg by loading a .urdf file it crashes.

The console shows this Error message:

```
REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 7937, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/siemens/.ros/log/c324fdc4-9769-11e4-99d8-c4d98785fc5f/moveit_setup_assistant-2.log].
log file: /home/siemens/.ros/log/c324fdc4-9769-11e4-99d8-c4d98785fc5f/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
```

the log file /moveit_setup_assistant-2.log does not exist!

This is the urdf file I used: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mtvf4ctmax9xq5/pr2.urdf?dl=0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200628/moveit-setup-assistant-crashes-when-loading-a-urdf/) by [TedK](https://answers.ros.org/users/21322/tedk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-08**:
Without access to the URDF we cannot really do anything I'm afraid. You might want to try and run the Setup Assistant in GDB. That could provide you with some more information as to where it is crashing precisely, but without proper debug symbols that will probably not be too helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS-Industrial training files also contain "working" solutions to each of the tasks.  They can be found in the "ref" directory as described at the bottom of this [page](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/Hydro%20PC%20Setup).

Instead of using "training_unit", you can call "training_ref" and that will switch you to the solved package.  You can also diff the working and ref directories to determine what may be causing the issue (assuming the ref version does not cause the same issue).

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2015-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem to be using the `pr2.urdf` from `pr2_description`. I cannot reproduce the crashes you are reporting either with your file, or the one from the package.

Does the Setup Assistant crash with other urdfs as well?

At the point where the Setup Assistant is loading the urdf, it starts to make proper use of your OpenGL subsystem. If anything is not ok there, it might lead to crashes such as your seeing. This is especially true if you are running Ubuntu/ROS in a VM.

In any case, make sure you have the correct (and up-to-date) drivers installed (check output of `glxinfo`, look at `OpenGL vendor/renderer/version` strings).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a problem with running the setup assistant on 32-bit OS's. This was taken directly from the Moveit! website:

> Note for Ubuntu 13.4 32 bit users: There is a bug with GCC 4.7 on Ubuntu 13.4 32bit with Eigen 3.1.2. It’s not likely to be fixed, so upgrade/downgrade your system to 13.4 64 bit resp. 12.4.

So basically, don't use a 32-bit OS, use a 64-bit one. It doesn't seem to be working on the Jetson TK1 or TX1, but as of this moment, those are all running 32-bit OS's as well.

---

Originally posted by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) with karma: 101 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1